# Why favour the standard WP loop over iterating over (new WP_Query())->get_posts()?

Tags: get-posts

The WP loop goes like this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    ...
```

Why is it preferred over the following?

```
foreach( (new WP_Query())->get_posts() as $post ) { ... }
```

To me, it's more apparent what is going on in the latter. I'm new to PHP and WP and I'm trying to understand why I should be using the former.

What do I gain by using the `standard loop`? Is iterating over `get_posts()` any less efficient?

Comment: Because WordPress already sets the instance of `WP_Query` for you, calling `new WP_Query()` will create another instance, which will be an overhead. Read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several reasons

### 1. Filters and Actions

By using the standard loop, you execute various filters and actions that plugins rely on.

Additionally, you set up `the_post` correctly, allowing functions such as `the_content` etc to work correctly. Some filters can even insert "posts" into the loop

### 2. Memory Efficiency

By fetching all the posts as an array, you're forcing `WP_Query` to take the data it has and create `WP_Post` objects. With a standard post loop these are created as they're needed

### 3. PHP Warnings

Your loop doesn't check if any posts were actually found, so it's impossible to give a "No posts available" style message. It'll also generate PHP warnings at times.

### 4. Overriding WP globals

By using `$post` you're overriding a global variable, which can have unintended consequences, especially if this loop is nested inside another loop you're unaware of

### 5. PHP Efficiency and Correctness

Creating an object inside a `foreach` condition is bad practice, as is creating and then using an object without error checking.

### 6. Debugging

A lot of tools and plugins assume you're using a standard loop and have been built to make life easier. By doing this you're throwing all of that away

### 7. There are Better Alternatives

#### array_walk

A **crude** but superior option to your foreach might actually be `array_walk`:

```
$q = new WP_Query([ ..args ]);
array_walk( $q->get_posts(), function( $post ) {
    //
});
```

Note that I don't recommend using `array_walk`.

#### PHP Generators

Now that's not to say you couldn't use a different style loop while still having all the advantages.

For example WP Scholar has an article showing a php generator based loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
   foreach ( wp_loop() as $post ) {
      echo '<h1>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</h1>';
   }
} else {
   echo '<h1>No posts found!</h1>';
}
```

This has the advantage that it still calls all the functions of a standard loop, but they've been abstracted away.

https://wpscholar.com/blog/creating-better-wordpress-loop/

I'm sure there are others, but a standard loop is reliable predictable and readable to all

Answer (score 4):

I advise you to take a look at the documentation:

- [The Loop | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)

you'll find more details there.

It follows a short abstract:

The Loop gives you access to:

**Template Tags**

- [Template Tags | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-tags/)
- [List of Template Tags | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/references/list-of-template-tags/)

**Conditional Tags**

- [Conditional Tags | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/)

Not all Template and Conditional Tags are The Loop dependent, for an overview for what to use in The Loop:

- [What the Loop Can Display | The Loop | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#what-the-loop-can-display)

Additionally, there are hooks that can be used with The Loop, like:

- [loop_start](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/loop_start/)
- [the_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/)
- [loop_end](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/loop_end/)

Looking at it  a bit more broadly you could include something like:

- [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/)

And all the filters listed under:

- [WP_Query Filters | Plugin API/Filter Refernce | WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#WP_Query_Filters)

Although the latter two technically do apply to a custom iteration over the `$wp_query->get_posts()` array too, but it is part of the system or process. And as a general rule it works better and more reliable if you use it inside the paradigm, so in this case by making use of The Loop.

Even if you need, sometimes it is unavoidable, additional loops, you don't have to do it outside The Loop paradigm:

- [Multiple Loops | The Loop | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#multiple-loops)

Because:

- [You can use `rewind_posts()` to loop through the same query a second time](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#using-rewind_posts);
- Or [create a secondary query and loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops), using [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#using-wp_reset_postdata) in the process.

Doing it this way gives you the benefits that come with The Loop, it is better integrated into how WordPress intended on doing it, and will create less overhead in the process.